# boot.img doesn't contain source code

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, kernel

I have a MTK soc phone rocking JB 4.2.2 with kernel 3.4.0. I have extracted the boot.img in Ubuntu using dsixda kitchen, however the extracted boot.img folder doesn't contain C source code. I have searched on Internet but didn't get any solutions.

1. Why isn't there any source code?
2. Where can I get the kernel 3.4.0 with Source Code

Answer (score 3):

C source code is compiled into executable code. There's very little need for C source code files to exist on Android devices.

If you want Linux kernel source you need to head over to Kernel.org.